Remove `[Text]` from the no-alt-text warning message
Feature request: Remove [Text] from the no-alt-text warning message.

Screenshot taken on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

This would be a better feature request if it looked at the explicit reason that "[Text]" is there, which the developer did explain, and provided an alternate method of addressing that reason. Not to mention, that this should explain why this change should be made, not just "make this change".

@Makyen only very few people actually see the [Text]. I've never seen it until today. But millions do see the other one, every time they upload image.

@ShadowWizard Right now, this question explains nothing. You're arguing reasons that aren't mentioned here, assuming, like this question, that people have context from at least a couple of other sources and making arguments that nobody has said anything about (at least not here).

@Makyen well, I don't agree. The error message is vague, the screenshot proves it. This feature request can stand on its own, and it can be rejected - it would be fair. (Though not relevant, Roomba will nuke it in a short while. Still, editing won't help as people don't agree with the concept itself.)

OK having read through the reasoning, I actually agree with you on this (though I stand by my reasons for including it in the first place!)
I'm now considering the following:

Images should have specific alt text briefly explaining what is shown. Use the square brackets immediately following the ! for this (which may currently contain enter image description here)

Does that work any better?
UPDATE:
This is now done.
After going back & forth somewhat, we elected to leave out the suggested link to avoid slightly conflicting advice around when alt text is not needed: as it's essentially impossible for us to detect whether or not text nearby the image already explains its content, we felt it better to push for users to always add something. Those who are aware of the nuance here will still be able to omit as this is technically still a warning which does not prevent submission.

Thanks, looks good to me.

Would it be possible to also link to a guide on how to write alt text? Not everybody will follow it, of course, but the easier you make it the more likely it will be. I wrote a brief alt-text specific guide, or a more in-depth accessibility guide for SE posts (although the lack of anchor links makes that less useful than I'd like).

Yes, much better indeed.

@Mithical yeah the link is a great idea

The no-alt-text warning message has been changed to:

Images should have specific alt text briefly explaining what is shown. Use the square brackets immediately following the '!' for this (which may currently contain 'enter image description here').

Example:


Finally, that's so much better. However, I think better edit the other answer by the developer who did it saying it's done.
